Is there a way in Python to validate return objects like in Typescript?
I am creating objects with complex structure with Python and I would like to have ability to validate them like in Typescript somehow before they are returned from function. Perfect option would be validate objects right in IDE, compilation time validation would also be ok. Validation in runtime is not that great, but also would be ok.


Say we have a class in Typescript:
class Example {
    property1: number;
    property2: string;
}

This code won't compile:
const testF = (): Example => {
    return {
        property1: 10
    }
}

will fail with error:
Property 'property2' is missing in type '{ property1: number; }' but required in type 'Example'.ts(2741)
index.ts(3, 5): 'property2' is declared here.

So I have to fix the object to make code start:
    return {
        property1: 10,
        property2: "332"
    }
}

Also if I change class, e.g.:
class Example {
    property1: string;
    property2: string;
}

Previous code won't fail with error:
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
index.ts(2, 5): The expected type comes from property 'property1' which is declared here on type 'Example'

I would like to validate objects in same way in Python, is it possible?

Compile-time validation in Python
Python doesn't have built-in compile-time type checking like TypeScript does, but Pydantic can be used to achieve TypeScript-like type checking and validation at compile time.
Pydantic is a data validation and configuration management library for Python that provides runtime validation of data structures using Python type annotations.
Here is an example of using Pydantic:
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError

class Example(BaseModel):
    property1: int
    property2: str

def test_f() -> Example:
    return Example(property1=10, property2="332")

try:
    example = test_f()
    print(example)
except ValidationError as e:
    print(e)

Pydantic documentation

I was thinking of pydantic, but not sure of its capabilities. I'll try and give you feedback, thank you!
